# GridView Remove first Row

Tags: c#, asp.net, t-sql, gridview

I am Producing a score card for a pool league and have 2 result set's. The first results set 'ds' is the frames & the second, 'dsres' is the result of the match.

I am outputting these results to a grid view like so:

```
GridView gv = new GridView();
gv.ID = "_gridview" + i;
gv.DataSource = ds;
gv.DataBind();
gv.CssClass = "Grid";

GridView gvres = new GridView();
gvres.ID = "_gridviewres" + i;
gvres.DataSource = dsres;
gvres.DataBind();
gvres.CssClass = "Grid";

ph.Controls.Add(gv);
ph.Controls.Add(gvres);
ph.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</br>"));
```

Both Grid views are added to asp:PlaceHolder 'ph' which produces two tables:

[image]

I would like to hide the second tables Header row.

I have tried `rows[0].Visible = false;` but this returns a out of bounds exception.

Please could someone tell me where I am going wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply the attribute to disable header like this. Make sure to put it before the .DataBind();

```
gvres.ShowHeader = false;
```

Comment: Yep, that did the trick. I tried that earlier but was putting it after the bind!

Comment: @Floyd I just tried the `gvres.Rows[0].Visible = false;` and it didn't give me an error. Instead it removed the first row of data. How did you try to implement this exactly?

Comment: I just put this line before the bind and got the same.

"Message=Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than."

Not too sure what is causing it but your answer did resolve the issue.

Comment: @Floyd Nevermind, I recreated that error. You must have put that before the DataBind, that means when trying to access Row at index 0, there is no such row and it throws that error. It works after the DataBind but it removed the record row and not the header. Good luck on your projects :)